# Масштабирование страницы на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css, webview

Есть страничка с минимальной шириной 1200px. При открытии на телефоне в горизонтальном положении, страница масштабируется, и никаких скроллов нет, но в вертикальном положении появляется скролл. Как можно сделать, чтобы при вертикальном открытии она сужалась до ширины экрана?

Страница: [hydroneva.ru](http://www.hydroneva.ru/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Адаптировать страницу под мобильные телефоны.
С помощью CSS-фреймворков (bootstrap, responsivegridsystem, Sceleton и пр.) и адаптировать существующий дизайн. Либо используйте CSS3 Media Queries.

Comment: Она отображается, как надо на телефоне, вопрос в масштабе при вертикальном просмотре

Comment: дык через медиа запросы изменять значения в классах